# Is Penn Teller's Bullshit a reliable source?

Tags: discussion

I love James Randi, The Skeptics Guide and Penn Point about as much as [Bullshit!](http://www.sho.com/site/ptbs/). And I love how on the last one they pick very heated topics to mostly defend their own (and maybe just apparently) biased point of view.

Some topics give birth to mostly satirical episodes such as Vaccination or the Bible, others deal with more delicate subjects such as Recycling or Cheerleaders. And so I wonder if there is any episode in which they are plain wrong? If there is, do they ever said something about it?

<sup>[original question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/is-penn-tellers-bullshit-a-reliable-source)</sup>

Comment: I suspect that Randi is a mild anthropogenic global warming doubter, like Penn and Teller.

Comment: @Andrew and myself.

Comment: I heard they apologised on-air about some mistakes in the Second-Hand Smoke episode, but I have been unable to find a reliable reference, so I am posting this as an unfounded rumour in the comments rather than an official answer.

Comment: @Oddthinking at the original question there was a comment with a link exactly to that - but I can't remember who gave it or where it linked to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say off the cuff it is [about as reliable as Mythbusters](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/450/is-mythbusters-ancedotal-evidence), in that they do set up some basic television science to verify their claims.

However, some of their shows are controversial even to skeptics:

http://www.science20.com/rationally_speaking/dear_penn_and_teller_bullshit

The libertarian slant of the show makes it a tad .. biased .. as well, and I think that's the source of a lot of the criticism, [per Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penn_%26_Teller:_Bullshit!).

> Many episodes aimed to debunk pseudoscientific ideas, paranormal beliefs, and popular fads and misconceptions, often from a libertarian point of view, the political philosophy espoused by both Penn and Teller.

Comment: Lovely references, [thanks](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/132/list-of-useful-sources-for-skeptics-se)! Sounds to me like they are reliable after all. :)