# I've got a deleted question. Why?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, deletion

[Here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/is-penn-tellers-bullshit-a-reliable-source). I know it's not personal, and I understand the same question is already finished under meta.

*But* why deleting a question that was already closed and had comments, back links, references and even worked as a good instance of a question that should not be asked on the main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [moved to meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/is-penn-tellers-bullshit-a-reliable-source), so it was deleted for being redundant.

Comment: My whole point is it wasn't redundant. In every other site duplicates way more redundant than this are never deleted and just stay closed - because it's one more reference and it has a reason to exist.

Comment: @Cawas: Considering it was deleted by Jeff Atwood, complaining about "lack of constancy across the network" isn't a really persuasive argument.

Comment: Well, biased again, but I hope someone can see this as a cute chance to contest Jeff! :P

Comment: @cawas why shouldn't it be deleted? it was migrated to meta! If you want to answer it go answer it there..

Comment: @Jeff for the same reason why so many duplicates are kept closed as duplicates instead of getting deleted. I know most of them have different (key)wording which is not the case. I thought the comments were somewhat valuable - at least to me - and as I said, people may learn better from seing a closed question on main than anything on meta. What I really don't know is **why deleting**. To me "for being redundant" means "for being bad" except I've listed many reasons why I don't consider it bad. Since I'm not an expert on SEN there came this question, with an answer I respect but don't get it.

Comment: @Cawas: Duplicates are kept for SEO reasons: having many posts with the same wording will increase the chances of someone landing on the right page/site. I don't think that reasoning applies here. Redundant Also redundant means redundant. It doesn't mean "bad."

Comment: Borror0, why wouldn't it apply here?

Comment: @Cawas:  Duplicates are potentially useful for search hits.  Having essentially the same question with several different wordings on the same site is good.  It means that people searching are more likely to wind up at the question, *and on the right site*.  Keeping questions on the wrong site will just cause confusion as to where they belong.

Comment: @David good point. Still, meta is essentially the same site and, even if it were completely different sites, the question just get a "*moved*" mark, not deleted. So, if this isn't the case to mark it as either which, I still don't see why deleting.