# Are answers based on personal (but documented) experience acceptable on skeptics?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers, off-topic

I would like to know if I could contribute by either asking questions or supplying answers that are based on my personal  but documented experience.

Obviously, I cannot prove anything scientifically, only what happened to me and how I am currently trying to resolve these multiple problems.

The context would be nutrition. Unrelated to unhealthy fad diets, but... questions or answers based on unconventional hypotheses.

Comment: The requirements we have for asking and answering questions are significantly different. It might be worth separating this into two questions along those lines, though meta isn't as strict about the Q&A format as main sites are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no.

Skeptics.SE is different than other Stack Exchange sites in that it requires questions to be "notable" enough, and answers to be referenced.

See:

- [FAQ for New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users)
- [FAQ: Must all answers be referenced?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced)
- [FAQ: What constitutes original research?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/faq-what-constitutes-original-research)
- [Meta: Is anecdotal evidence sufficient for answers?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/424/is-anecdotal-evidence-sufficient-for-answers)
- [All meta questions tagged "FAQ"](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes&pageSize=15)

Comment: I had a sneaky suspicion that was going to be the answer. It's a shame that personal experience, documented, is not considered reliable or relevant. By documented I mean blood tests, medical exams etc. Thanks for the links.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No problem, welcome to the site! I don't want to completely rule it out, it may depend on the exact nature of the documentation/evidence. I mean, if your medical situation is so unique that it been published it medical journals, then that would certainly seem notable. And questions like "my doctor told me (really weird thing), is that really true?" might be notable if you can find other people on the internet that seem to believe it. (Although versions of that might be better on https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *I mean, if your medical situation is so unique that it been published it medical journals,* No, no, no. Nothing as grandiose as that. I'm no medical phenomena. I just wanted to tell my little story, which is still ongoing by the way.

Comment: @Mari-LouA skeptics.SE's scope and requirements are specific and narrow. This isn't a judgement on the reliability of your personal experience; it just doesn't fit the requirements.