# How can I delete my Skeptics account?

Tags: support

I have other S.E. profiles, so I only want this one gone.

Without going into detail, I feel like this is not the place for me and I want out.

Comment: It'd be a shame to see you leave Roland. But if you want to go that's your choice. This site annoys the heck out of me at times but I think that's part of the appeal.

Comment: @boehj I would be pleased to see better from the site, because it has potential, but it will require for 2 things: 1. users need to be more friendly to new comers. 2. people with a bias on something, should keep the bias offline :D...

(this is said from looking at other questions/answers, not so much my own, though comments on my own do begin to feel the same as those I've seen before).

Comment: I'd be with you 100% on point 1) there. I've been fairly lucky re: point 2) thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roland, I have to say it's shame you are going. I saw your answers to questions today and they weren't far off the mark.

Skeptics is slightly different as anything that is said in answers has to be [referenced](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/must-all-claims-be-referenced).

That doesn't mean your answers were wrong, but they need to be supported by references and not just be claims.

There are a few people here that are a bit quick jump on questions and answers, but I think it's important that everyone can be a part of the site and participate.

Have a look around at some of the other answers provided by other users and we hope you can help us do some research and provide us with some more good answers.

Thanks for your input and I hope you can stay around.

Comment: Well my challenge comes from the fact that I've been watching some questions/answers before I joined, was disappointed, and still decided to go ahead and join just to give this site the benefit of the doubt. I'm sorry I did that. However, as you suggest, I'll hang around a bit longer and see...

Answer (score 2):

We can delete your profile here, if that is what you want. Just put "please delete me" into your profile, we will delete the account after a short while (we give some time for users to reconsider).

This will have no effect on your other SE accounts.

Comment: Hi fabian. I tagged my profile info with the desired sentence. please delete me. I will not reconsider, so you can go ahead. Thanks!