# Why, exactly, was this pre-migration answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

It's not that I want to raise a particular ruckus, but I [posted an answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/does-camera-flash-destroy-art/6265#6265) to the question [Does camera flash destroy art?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/does-camera-flash-destroy-art) on the Photo.SE site before it was migrated here. The answer received 23 upvotes before deletion, which indicates to me that it might, just might, have met some sort of minimum standard.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the answer, or was it simply that I was not a member of this SE site? If it's a keep-it-in-the-community thing, I'll accept that as a valid reason -- these sites are, at least to a degree, based on a sort of verifiable level of trust that's reflected by reputation. If, on the other hand, there is a fundamental problem with the content of the answer, I'd like to know what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migration of that question was problematic because [we require references for all significant claims](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced), which is a standard most of the migrated answers don't meet. This is just a fundamental difference between Skeptics and the other SE sites.

This is somewhat unfair to the existing answers, as they were written under different rules and expectations, we usually would try to avoid migrations with many upvoted answers.

I suspect that the answer was outright deleted because you did not have an account on this site, so a comment asking for references would not have notified you. Usually we would ask for references in a comment before doing anything else, but the migration causes some complications here.

I'll undelete the answer for now, it would be great if you could add some references to support the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I included search terms rather than links to particular papers in the original answer specifically to avoid the appearance of bias (for every paper, there is an equal and opposite rebuttal paper). On Photo.SE, in particular, many of the sources of outside information show a definite bias (brand favoritism and so forth) that need to have a *caveat* appended to them; if the facts are little disputed, then an open search is usually the best option.

Comment: @StanRogers, thanks for adding the sources. I would have suggested that you add them and flag for undelete, but you had no user on this site.