# Does "Unsourced material may be challenged and removed" imply a challenge?

Tags: discussion, citations

I've been getting [warnings on my post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/does-hot-water-freeze-faster-than-cold-water/3505#3505) for "lack of references".

No, I don't have any. I just thought I'd post this because it was (1) relevant, and (2) research I'd done myself, with (what I believe) to be accurate data, and (3) in support of the question/answer.

It's not like I have anything to gain by this answer (aside from the rep points, I guess...) so I'm not going to spend hours/days/weeks looking for corroborating research just to keep it on the site (why should I?) and so, frankly, as sad as I would be to see it go, I couldn't care less if moderators deleted it.

Not to mention that I think I already did my part by going through the trouble of finding my research from many years ago from my backups (which I had *actually made* in 5th grade, believe it or not...).

So I wonder: **What would anyone gain from deleting my post?**

It seems to me that the warning:

> *Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.*

seems to be saying, rather,

> *Your unsourced material **will** be removed **without a challenge**.*

because really, I don't see anyone "challenging" my post, and yet I keep on getting this (*quite* annoying, to be honest) warning.

So, do we really need to **auto**-challenge every post without a reference, even though there is no real reason to? Or could the warnings be made so as they would only pop up when someone *actually* challenges a post?

Comment: What is that you are trying to ask here? We decided that we only want referenced posts, what should we do if you disagree and ignore us?

Comment: @Sklivvz: I'm asking if the quote "*may* be challenged" is really intended to mean "*is automatically* challenged". If so, then should we change it, and then get my post deleted already? And if not, then why is my post automatically "challenged" without anyone claiming that it is wrong?

Comment: @Mehrdad - It is a challenge itself.  You may also be challenged in comments.  Or they could just flag your post where you would get no notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notice has obviously a *general text* because it must be used in many places, on any post and on any SE site.

You are free to open a thread on Meta.SO if you can think of a better wording - [I've done so myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126301/please-improve-the-post-annotations) for different reasons!

However, the comments on your post are much more specific than the generic blurb:

> @LarianLeQuella: Does original research count? – Mehrdad Jan 13 at 21:20
>   1
>
> Only if it was published and peer reviewed. :) – Larian LeQuella Jan 13 at 21:22

[...]

> There is a discussion on meta that talks about the type of references that are required here. – Larian LeQuella Jan 13 at 21:28
>
> @LarianLeQuella: Never seen the discussion, but I didn't see anything like that in the FAQ or anything. I'll remove it once it becomes a rule. :) – Mehrdad Jan 13 at 21:30

The rule has been extensively debated on skeptics:

- it is our [fifth question ever](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5) on meta!
- there are [99 questions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=references) about it as of now
- it's clearly spelt out in our [welcome post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)

---

To answer your question more explicitly:

The challenge is not automatically implied. Challenges are manual (and on specific points). In practice it means that someone may call you on any unreferenced points. It's a warning that this may happen.

Your material may be challenged in a comment, in another post, on meta, as a flag, in chat...

It is also a warning giving you fair notice that your post *may* be deleted by a moderator or the community if it is not referenced.

Comment: A few notes... (1) I never saw the welcome post (hadn't even logged in since the beginning of March...); that was two months later than the comments above; (2) You seemed to cherry-pick my old comments in support of your answer without ever noting that, after I received the warning, I went and *looked for my "research"* to back up my answer (to avoid deleting my answer), so at least it's *supported*, if only by my own evidence. (I don't plan on removing it myself anymore.) (3) **Most important:** *You still avoided answering my question* of whether the "challenge" is automatic or manual.

Comment: @Mehrdad done. Is it OK?

Comment: +1 much better now, thanks. So just to clarify: it's more like Wikipedia's *[Citation needed]* tag (i.e. informative), rather than a warning-we're-about-to-remove-your-post-unless-you-can-save-it-soon (i.e. a warning of a definite action planned to come)? (
 In the latter case, I'll probably ignore it, since I don't have anything to add...)

Comment: As I said, it's a warning. The post *may* be deleted in the future. Ignore it at your own risk. :-)

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. :) I'm not the one losing anything here if it gets deleted so I think I'm gonna ignore it.