# Where's the link error from?

Tags: bug, references, answers

I've noticed several times that someone will post a poorly researched answer, and someone will leave a comment that says: (e.g. [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19174/is-it-good-to-drink-coke-when-sick#comment75155_19244),[here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19462/will-intranasal-application-of-breast-milk-treat-colds#comment76005_19474) ,[here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18688/is-jesus-christs-birth-day-march-28th#comment72949_18734), [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18352/do-memory-foam-mattresses-cause-inflammation#comment71046_18358), and [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18489/is-reaction-time-correlated-with-intelligence#comment72042_18557)).

> Welcome to [Skeptics Stack Exchange](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! Please provide some [references](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/5) to support your claims.

Now, the [second link](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/5) is non-existent. To me, the explanation seems likely to be that there's some "standard" text with the wrong link. The correct link appears to be [this](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5), which is given [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18489/is-reaction-time-correlated-with-intelligence#comment72070_18563), for example. So could someone fix whatever causing these errors?

I'm not sure if this is a site bug or a person bug, so I'm tagging this bug.

You can see several more examples by searching [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="Welcome+to+Skeptics+Stack+Exchange%21+Please+provide+some+references+to+support+your+claims.").

Comment: Sklivvz uses the Pro Forma comment script for those, this looks like a mistake in his template.

Comment: Getting bug reports for my proforma config: achievement unlocked!

Comment: Correcting a moderator: achievement unlocked!