# Why was my answer edited?

Tags: discussion

[My answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/35940/revisions) to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35927/are-we-in-a-low-co2-period-compared-to-the-last-590-million-years) was heavily edited and I'm not sure why.
The OP seems to be asking if the "paper" somehow disproves man-made climate change and pointing out biases and logical falicies in the arguments by the author very relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Skeptics is a little different than other sites on the network. Pertinent to this question, [facts in answers need citation](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced). Your answer may very well be correct, but it's backed only by a link to Wikipedia. For that reason, a moderator added a [post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172592/1438):

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

Rather than deleting the answer outright, another moderator removed the most speculative bits of the answer. It still could use some more references (perhaps from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambrian#References)), however. On this site, it's not enough to have a correct answer; you need to backup your answer with citations. Otherwise, it's difficult for the layperson to separate a truthful answer from a bogus one.

Comment: I think that notice was in regards to the rest of the answer, not the part that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The question wasn't whether the entire paper/speech undermined the consensus on Climate Change, but whether one particular fact did.

Parts of your answer were (a) not referenced, and (b) not related to the claim.

You were attempting to discredit the entire speech of Rutan - rather than just the claim in question. Unfortunately, there were a number of flaws in your argument (including a lack of references). I could have tried to edit it into shape, and demand references, but given it was off-topic, it seemed better to simply delete them to salvage the part that was related to the claim.

(The parts that survived that *were* referenced, were only referenced with Wikipedia, which is not a reliable source for controversial facts, but that's a separate issue.)