# Proposal for little sidebar guidance

Tags: feature-request

Many specialised Stack Exchange sites have a little sidebar giving important context about the site. For example, [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) has:

> Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

[Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) has:

> Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

I'd like to suggest Skeptics acquire one! The [FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) indicates specifically that this is a different sort of SE to most, and that many people are surprised by this fact, and that the site can come across as unfriendly because of it. The FAQ actually spends a *lot* of effort on saying this, which suggests that the community finds it to be a problem in practice. I propose that a little sidebar would be help the site appear friendlier by removing the surprise. It could say something like the following (wording, of course, entirely up for debate):

> Unlike most Stack Exchange sites, Skeptics Stack Exchange is primarily an aggregator of reputable references about notable claims. Please read [the welcome FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) for information about how this unusual focus affects questions and answers.

---

[Bikeshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality)-bait follows:

The phrasing I chose is my best guess at what would have prevented me from making a certain mistake on this SE. I could justify it by pointing to [the FAQ on referencing](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced), but in fact my main purpose here is to help prevent other people from making the same mistake, rather than merely to give the most accurate summary of what this SE is for. I believe that this is best done by emphasising that the point is not to answer questions per se, but to attempt to present references, and secondarily to present the "scientific consensus" (whatever that may mean).

Comment: At some point users should be expected to read the sites rules and guidelines and not need to have a banner to spell out the basics at all times.

Comment: If that's the stance, I have no skin in the game; but I do think it would help to have *some* way to indicate to new posters that "however experienced you are on other SEs, your experience does not translate to this one, where you do need to fully read all the rules before considering whether to post". Most SEs don't have that property. But it's up to the community to decide whether "people aren't reading our guidelines" happens enough to take further action on it; I certainly can't judge that, I just assumed it was true from the little I have seen.

Comment: Putting the bikeshedding aside, I like the idea. I have never noticed these sidebars before. I wonder how to make one. I'll go find out.

Comment: The [ask popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/323179) is a better place for advice about asking questions. The sidebar might then be better used to explain that answers must have references. Assuming people read, of course.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think "answers must have references" does not actually get at the heart of what makes this SE different from every other, and is deeply misleading to someone who merely sees the word "skeptic" and reads the FAQ welcome post. The vital difference between this SE and every other, as I see it, is that this SE does not particularly care about what the asker had in their mind when they asked their question. Every other SE I've encountered is about teaching the question-asker; this SE is instead about noting whether the conclusion the question-asker stated is correct or not.

Comment: (I say this merely as someone who is trying to stop people undergoing the same misunderstanding as I did last week. It took me some hours of on-and-off thinking to determine a guiding philosophy which made the rules here seem even slightly consistent, and the best way I can think of to convey the insight in very few words is: "the question-asker's argument is entirely irrelevant; only the concluding line of the argument matters, and additionally you must demonstrate that you are presenting 'the scientific consensus' on that line, for whatever those words mean in the context of the question".)

Comment: (I note in particular that this is a rather specific interpretation of the phrase "scientific scepticism"! A normie sceptic would be quite happy to respond to a bogus claim with the statement "your argument is entirely specious, for the following reasons" and move on with life: you're supposed to have evidence of a thing if you want to believe it, and since the argument was false, you've been given no evidence. But this SE takes a much stronger view, and this is not very obvious from the various FAQ.)